# How to best create a button inside a canvas using dart:html

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, dart

I'm working on a very simple html5 game using dart and canvas. I would like to have buttons on the canvas, but for some reason I'm having trouble figuring out how to best create the button.

I am trying to keep everything abstracted to eventually be able to pull the game to Flutter.

Some ideas I have:

- I assume there is some sort of built-in Button class in the canvas. I could create an abstract button class, and implement a CanvasButton class that uses the built-in canvas button. I haven't found this Button class yet, though.
- create my own Button class... use an image, and compare the click location to the position of the Button to determine whether it is clicked.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there an example dart web game tutorial somewhere that includes a button inside the canvas?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd say option 2 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API should show all you can do in a canvas. There might be JS libs out there that provide code for such a button, probably not for Dart yet, but shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not built-in button class that gets drawn directly onto the canvas. There are a couple of options I can think of:

1. Use a normal html button, add it to the DOM and have it sit above the canvas (by utilizing z-index).
2. Create a function that draws a rectangle. Store the position of the rectangle. Listen to the canvas's onClick stream and check the position of each click to see if it is in the rectangle.

Comment: Yeah... Im working on option 2 here. Not sure I understand why the button object doesn't exist, but I figured option 2 would work better when I eventually try to port to flutter. (Starting with a basic web game, but hoping to eventually release for iOS/android).

Comment: Yeah definitely agree if you are going to port to flutter. I don't know a whole lot about flutter though.